# UTG900E output specification

Tags: power-supply, waveform, function-generator, dds

The datasheet of [UTG900E](https://instruments.uni-trend.com/EU-EN/waveformgenerators/utg900e.html) Waveform generator says it can output up to 10 Vpp on a 50 ohm load, but in chapter 3.3.1 is stated the load can be set between 1 and 999 ohm.

Nowhere in the datasheet I see anything about current output, unless the requirements for power supply that is 5V 2A.

Connecting a load of 1 ohm with the maximum amplitude of 10 Vpp, it would require a peak current of 10 V / 1 ohm = 10 A, OR, if I assume the load settings would change the output impedance of the device to match the following one, it can be the half - still too high for the power requirements.
Since the minimum frequency is as low as 1 uHz it's virtually a DC.

How can it source so much current?

Comment: probably can't.

Comment: This is a product usage question, albeit it is an electrical engineering related product. Have you read the manual? What if the menu just sets your assumed load impedance, so you get the assumed voltage value that is on screen, adjusted based on device output impedance?

Comment: @Justme of course I read the manual, in fact I reported the sentences written there. Even if the load impedance is "assumed" how can it source the current?

Comment: @Justme which is the correct site where ask my question then?

Comment: When it says the load can be between 1 and 9999 it really means that the output impedance can be set between 1 and 9999 where 50 is a default value. Maximum current is 100 mA.

Comment: @Andyaka please, can you show me in the datasheet where is the information about 100 mA of maximum output current?